# Direct Limit of Polynomials

Tags: commutative-algebra, limits-colimits

This is probably a very stupid question, but what is the direct limit $\lim k[x]/x^n$, where the map $k[x]/x^n \to k[x]/x^{n+1}$ is given by multiplication by $x$. For $\mathbb{Z}/p$ this is the Prufer group. I know I can write it as an infinite disjoint union quotienting a relation, but I am looking for an explicit description.

Comment: Multiplication by $x$ is not a ring homomorphism (assuming rings to be unital). Are you sure you don’t want to have the direction of the maps reversed?

Comment: The direction is correct. See also the Prüfer group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $R$ is any commutative ring and $p \in R$ is an element, then you can consider the $R$-module
$$R/p^{\infty} := \varinjlim R/p^n$$
with the transition maps $p : R/p^n \to R/p^{n+1}$. Many properties which work for $R=\mathbb{Z}$ and prime numbers $p$ ([Prüfer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group)) carry over to the case that $ R$ is a PID and $p$ is a prime element, as in your example. I do not think that the restriction to polynomial rings is beneficial here to understand what is going on. For example:

- $R/p^{\infty}$  is isomorphic to the submodule $R[1/p]/R$ of $Q(R)/R$.
- $R/p^{\infty}$ is a torsion divisible $R$-module. (Actually, one can show that every divisible $R$-module is a direct sum of copies of $R/p^{\infty}$ and $Q(R)$.)
- $R/p^{\infty}$ admits a presentation $\langle x_1,x_2,\dotsc : p x_1 = 0, \, x_1 = p x_2, \, x_2 = p x_3,\, \dotsc \rangle$ as $R$-module.
- There is an isomorphism of rings $\mathrm{End}(R/p^{\infty}) \cong \varprojlim R/p^n$.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. I want to know if this requires $p$ is non-torsion.

Comment: $R$ is a PID and $p$ is a prime element, hence no zero divisor. Your example is $R=K[x]$ and $p=x$.

Comment: Yes, thats true. I was asking the situation in your solution. In my mind, I actually want to have a direct limit of D-modules of formal families.  Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: Ok, but what is your question exactly?

Comment: I want to confirm that your answer doesn't use $p$ is torsion free.